# Checking if single field is valid

Tags: django, django-views

I'm attempting to check to see if the image field in my form is valid and, if its not, reset it to None. My code in views.py looks like this. I've commented on the 2 lines that kind of explain my intentions, but aren't valid/working.

```
def edit_user_profile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditUserProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()            
            return redirect('/accounts/profile/websitesetup2/')

        else:
            if form.image.is_valid:         #not valid code (problem a)
                pass
            else:
                form.image = None           #not valid code (problem b)

            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/page1.html', args)

    else:
        form = EditUserProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'accounts/page1.html', args)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to:

a) Check to see if just the image field is valid

b) Reset the image field to None

I want to do this as an image that throws an error shows up like this when the form is rerendered

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGXkX.jpg

If you have any ideas, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the image field is valid, it should be in `cleaned_data`, so you could try to to access that and if it fails remove the image field from the Forms errors. This would render your Template again but won't render the error message at the image-field. Is this really what you want?

```
if form.is_valid():
        form.save()            
        return redirect('/accounts/profile/websitesetup2/')

    else:
        try:
            # if we can access image in cleaned_data, it means it is valid
            form.cleaned_data['image']
        except KeyError:
            # if we get a KeyError, it means the image is not valid
            del form._errors['image']
        finally:
            args = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/page1.html', args)
```

Comment: I added print statements in the try and except parts of the code and it looks like neither of them execute during the upload for a valid image and an invalid image. Also, I need errors to be displayed on the form and this kind of breaks that functionality.

Comment: I tested it on a Form with CharFields, where it works. You could try stepping through with the debugger of your IDE to see what exactly is going on.

Comment: running a print statement after the code within the try and except tags does the same thing, doesn't it? I.e. if the print statement doesn't run, it means the try / except statement didn't get executed. Is there a reason you tried with a CharField? Wouldn't the results be different?

Comment: It does, yes. But at least from my experience, I usually learn something when debugging through the code step by step. I used CharFields, as I could easily test it with an existing test project of mine. As it currently stands I'm afraid I can't help you any further. Have you checked that your initial code is reaching the appropriate lines?

Comment: No worries. I really appreciate that you reached out to me even if we weren't able to get this resolved. I'll play around with it a bit more. Not quite sure what you mean when you say "initial code is reaching the appropriate lines?"

Comment: As you've written, the print statements in try-except weren't reached. It might be interesting whether your initial code was reached, i.e. the `else` when the form is not valid. Or if your code is maybe failing somewhere else, causing us to look into the wrong direction

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Good call. I'll check it out.